# Finding Recursion in XSD using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xsd, xslt-1.0

I am trying to find recursion in XSD using XSLT. Can anyone suggest any technique?

Example

```
<xs:element name="nodes">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="node" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="node">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="node" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="text" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Here "node" is recursively used in XSD. I am trying to write an XSLT to find recursive elements in XSD.

Answer (score 0):

The following XPath will find all elements that also have a element with the ref attribute

```
//xs:element[@name=//xs:element/@ref]/@name
```

The next XPath will find elements that have childs containing the same element with the ref attribute:

```
//xs:element[@name=descendant-or-self::xs:element/@ref]/@name
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty tough if you want to find all possible ways of achieving the recursion, e.g. recursion via any number of intermediaries, and doing it via named model groups in an imported schema document. It amounts to writing an XML schema document processor in XSLT (i.e. one that converts the XML representation of a schema to the internal schema component representation).

You are probably better off letting someone else build the schema component model for you, and working off that. Saxon offers an XML representation of the schema component model (SCM), Xalan offers a Java API to it.